# Best way to implement UIPageControl?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uipageviewcontroller

In my app I have a registration page for any new users. At the moment Im using UIPageControl on a view controller so that when a user swipes left a new set of textfields are displayed. I have it so that when the user swipes to the left the previous textfields are hidden. I don't think this is the best way of implementing UIPageControl. I would like to implement it in such a way that when the user swipes to the left the new text boxes slide in with the swipe instead of just appearing. Also when the user swipes back i have to make the previous text fields unhidden but then they don't keep the information that the user has already typed into them.[image]

Any ideas of how to best implement UIPageControl or even the best way to implement a registration form like this?

Thanks a million!

Comment: You might want to use a UIScrollView for a higher level of granular control. UIPageController can be very limited I've found (I NEVER use it personally)

Comment: Do not say UIPageControl if you mean UIPageViewController. They are totally different things.

Answer (score 0):

If this is a march through a series of forms that the user must fill out in order, you could use instead a UINavigationController (which, indeed, is what is suggested by the Back button already in your interface)...

The *real* problem, however, seems to be that you are using UIPageViewController incorrectly: if the user is to be able to go back and forth between views and the information previously entered is to be present, it is up to *you* to use a different view controller for each view and to save the entered information when the user leaves a view controller and to restore it when the user summons that same view controller again.

This is something you would need to do no matter *what* implementation you choose, because a view controller can always be destroyed when its view is not being seen. Model-view-controller! It is up to you to maintain the model (the data) - do not rely on the mere view to maintain it for you.